# How can I align two images one of which has been warped?

Tags: images, gis, transform

Is there any software that can be used to warp two images so they can be aligned? I'm not sure, but I think is this is known as [image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) or [image rectification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_rectification).

**Background**
I'm using Adobe Illustrator to draw a map of a nature reserve. So far it is essentially a trace of the geographical features visible in the Google Satellite view. The intention is that the map will be split into tiles and displayed as a Google Maps layer on the nature reserve's website, so the map is drawn in the Mercator projection used by Google Maps.

I've been given another map of the nature reserve, as a high resolution image, which contains detailed routes for paths which run under trees hence are not visible in the satellite view. Hence I would like to overlay this map onto my map so I can trace these paths and display them. However, this map is based on the UK Ordnance Survey map, which is in a different projection than the Mercator used by Google Maps. Worse than that, the author of the map has used non-linear transforms to skew and warp it (the central area has been expanded in a non-linear way to accentuate the highlights in the middle of the reserve).

So I'm looking for software which I can use to define a set of reference control points in each image, such that one image can be warped to align with the other.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found one potential solution. [R2V](http://www.ablesw.com/r2v/index.html) is an image manipulation tool by Able Software. It has the [image warping functionality](http://www.ablesw.com/r2v/imgwarp.html) I'm looking for to rectify two images, but the [price list](http://www.ablesw.com/r2v/price.html) puts it at US$795, so I think I'll keep looking for a freeware solution...